# Blue Screen while running OpenCV 3.1 mini-application

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I'm having several problems to run my OpenCV based projects on my computer. I'm using OpenCV 3.1.0 with Visual Studio 2015 so i'm using vc14 .lib and .dll. The official web page of OpenCV says that 3.1.0 has Visual Studio 14 2015 support so i don't think that this is the problem.

The code i'm running is this :

```
enter code here
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>
#include<opencv2\objdetect\objdetect.hpp>
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include<vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
       CascadeClassifier face_cascade, eye_cascade;
   if (!face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")) {
    printf("Error loading cascade file for face");
    return 1;
}
if (!eye_cascade.load("haarcascade_eye.xml")) {
    printf("Error loading cascade file for eye");
    return 1;
}
VideoCapture capture(0); //-1, 0, 1 device id
if (!capture.isOpened())
{
    printf("error to initialize camera");
    return 1;
}
Mat cap_img, gray_img;
vector<Rect> faces, eyes;
while (1)
{
    capture >> cap_img;
    waitKey(10);
    cvtColor(cap_img, gray_img, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::equalizeHist(gray_img, gray_img);
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img, faces, 1.1, 10, CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE | CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize(0, 0), cvSize(300, 300));
    for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
    {
        Point pt1(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + faces[i].height);
        Point pt2(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);
        Mat faceROI = gray_img(faces[i]);
        eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));
        for (size_t j = 0; j< eyes.size(); j++)
        {
            //Point center(faces[i].x+eyes[j].x+eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y+eyes[j].y+eyes[j].height*0.5);
            Point center(faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height*0.5);
            int radius = cvRound((eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25);
            circle(cap_img, center, radius, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2, 8, 0);
        }
        rectangle(cap_img, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);
    }
    imshow("Result", cap_img);
    waitKey(3);
    char c = waitKey(3);
    if (c == 27)
        break;
}
return 0;
}
```

It's just an example that i found on the internet.

I really want to learn about OpenCV but i can't run anything :(

I'm using Windows 8.1

The blue screen is like in the link below:

https://cdn.xtremerain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Kernel-Security-Check-Failure-HD-Screenshot.jpg

**EDIT**: It's very strange, though that it was solved by installing windows 10 but it doesn't.

I realized that it only happens when i close the app.

Comment: I would expect a blue screen to be caused from a bug in a driver or the OS. The OS should prevent an application from causing a blue screen.

Comment: Very strange, i though that it was solved but it doesn't. Now i realize it only happen when i close my program.

Comment: Hi Ariel Amor Garcia! I have the same problem, when I close the Application it crashes the windows 10 and give the same error as you mentioned, I am using OpenCV 3.1.0 with Java Language. Do you have any solution yet?

Comment: Hi @BahramdunAdil i've reinstalled my windows 10 now i think its all fine nothing crashes and i can work propertly. It's my only solution at the moment :(

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did the same step as you did (Reinstall the windows 10), then everything goes well, but after some days this problem again happened. So I don't want to reinstall the windows for 3rd, 4th, ...nth time. I don't why this problem happened, I think this problem was came when the windows 10 upgraded, before everything was OK.

Comment: I'll tell if this is reproduced in my comupter in the future, i hope not! And if you find a solution post it here it would be very helpfull :). Thanks!

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Hi dude, i've found the problem here. The problem is about my graphic card driver that has some incompatibility with OpenCV 3.1 I've got a GTX 950M.

Comment: Thank you for remember me! It means that I need to update the graphic card driver? I am using Invidia GeForce GT 640M with the latest driver update.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Try tu uninstall the driver or to work with the driver that has windows 10 installed not the official last driver of Nvidia. May in future updates of the Nvidia driver this issue is solved.

Comment: @ArielAmorGarcia Yes you are right, the problem was with graphic card driver, I reinstalled it again, and it works well, but I also afraid if this problem happened again, I hope the has solved for ever. :) Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check roi rectangle is fit in image area. detectMultiScale can give rectangles that will be partially located out of image.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem now, i can run the application but when i close it it crashes and shows me the BSOD with the message in the image.  :(

Comment: It may be camera driver issue. You can check it using still images (imread) instead of video. Also try to call destroyAllWindows() at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Suffered from the exact same issue, OpenCV 3 can cause issues with certain Nvidia drivers. Updating to the latest graphics driver solved the issue immediately!